# Developing a multi-functionality commercial website

Tags: drupal, joomla, content-management-system

I am interested developing a website related to trading card collecting. I may be interested in following functionality:

Card Display (Display all cards in existence)

User Management (Member Accounts)

User Inventory (Member's cards chosen from card display)

E-Commerce (capability to sell individual or sets of cards and accessories)

Forum

Blog

Is there a one package solution out there (Joomla, Drupal, etc.) or do I need to have this developed using a combination of HTML5/JavaScript & CSS?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think Joomla 2.5 might be the way to go on this one. It already has user management so that is that covered.

For the forum, you can use [Kunena](http://kunena.org), which integrates fully.

As for a [blog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog), there are lots to choose from, commercial and non-commercial.

For the e-commerce side, I would personally recommend using [VirtueMart](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/129) or [JoomShopping](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/5378)

I think [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210) will be far better for the user management, as you can add custom fields for profiles and it integrates with many extensions such as the Kunena Forum.

Hope this helps.

Comment: those sound like great suggestions! I am looking at them now. The only thing you didn't mention would be a way to display photos of all the Trading Cards in existence, and a way for members to link to those cards they have in their collection. Can this be done? Or would this have to be done using HTML5/Javascript and a mySQL database? - thanx

Comment: I have never looked into doing that sort of thing but I have a strong feeling it will be possible in the likes of community builer. worth giving it a try and if not, there might be some other extensions for extended profiles. might come at a price though :/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this I think would be:

**Blog** -> Wordpress

**Forum** -> Buddypress (Wordpress plugin)

**eCommerce** -> [Zenshop](http://demo.fabthemes.com/zenshop/)

Or for a professional solution develop this from grounds up.